# pdf viewer in iOS

Tags: ios, pdf

I am making a pdf viewer in ios application. So i used the leaves from `github` so as to have `curl effect`. Then i added thumbnails to it by using the method

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromPDFWithDocumentRef:(CGPDFDocumentRef)documentRef andPageNumber:(int)pageNumber{

    CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(documentRef, pageNumber);
    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMinX(pageRect),CGRectGetMaxY(pageRect));
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -(pageRect.origin.x), -(pageRect.origin.y));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pageRef);

    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return finalImage;
}
```

here i call for every pages that i have. Thus i added thumbnails at the bottom of the view controller. on clicking any of the thumbnail i should navigate to the corresponding page. 
Luckily i have delegate in which i should pass `PageIndex` and `CGContextRef` so as to go to the corresponding page.

```
- (void)renderPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    reqContext = ctx;
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(_pdf, index + 1);
    CGAffineTransform transform = aspectFit(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox),
                                            CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(reqContext));
    CGContextConcatCTM(reqContext, transform);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(reqContext, page);
    NSLog(@"index is %d",index);
    //NSLog(@"%@",reqContext);

}
```

The above code is there in the leaves that i got from the github. Now i saw in github that if i call this delegate the corresponding page can be displayed. Now i could pass the pageIndex but could not pass `CGContextRef` by any means.

Is there any other way that i could display the page?

Comment: `CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(_pdf, index);` Use this.

Comment: In the method renderPageAtIndex method, the thing is already there... what i want is the context to be passed to the method so as to draw the pdf page in the context.